# Non linear model plotting issues using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, nls

I have a problem plotting an NLS-fit via stat_smooth. Interestingly, the curve of the fit is shifted in the negative y direction. Does anyone know what could be the reason for this? Below is the code, data and a sample graph (URL):

```
y<-c(0.686, 0.674, 0.631, 0.580, 0.520, 0.440, 0.411, 0.401, 0.338, 0.262, 0.218, 0.703, 0.628,0.584, 0.547, 0.513, 0.457, 0.395, 0.372, 0.326, 0.255, 0.213, 0.760, 0.684, 0.622, 0.577, 0.550, 0.463, 0.395, 0.352, 0.311, 0.244, 0.212)
x<-c(0.03,  0.08,  0.15,  0.23,  0.30,  0.75,  1.50,  2.25,  3.01,  7.52, 15.03,  0.03,  0.08, 0.15,  0.23,  0.30,  0.75,  1.50,  2.25,  3.01,  7.52, 15.03,  0.03,  0.08,  0.15,  0.23,0.30,  0.75,  1.50,  2.25,  3.01,  7.52, 15.03)  
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y)) 
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = log10(y) ~ c1*log10(x)+c2,
              method.args=list(start=list(c1=-0.2,c2=-0.4)),
              se=FALSE)
```

[image]

Many thanks
XEZ

Comment: That's because the fitted values return `log10(y)` instead of y, e.g.  add geom_point(aes(x = x, y = log10(y)) and you will get a perfect fit. Maybe you want `y ~ c1*log10(x)+c2`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would like to compare different models in one plot, including the log-log model (log(y) ~c1*log(x)+c2) I presented as well as the level-log-model (y ~c1*log(x)+c2) suggested by you. Is it somehow possible to do this via ggplot?

Answer (score 1):

Like stefan mentioned in the comments, it's because you're fitting `log10(y)`. One solution other that transforming the input values, is to inverse the log transformation after the fit has been calculated. You can do this by using the `stage()` function:

```r
library(ggplot2)

y<-c(0.686, 0.674, 0.631, 0.580, 0.520, 0.440, 0.411, 0.401, 0.338, 0.262, 0.218, 0.703, 0.628,0.584, 0.547, 0.513, 0.457, 0.395, 0.372, 0.326, 0.255, 0.213, 0.760, 0.684, 0.622, 0.577, 0.550, 0.463, 0.395, 0.352, 0.311, 0.244, 0.212)
x<-c(0.03,  0.08,  0.15,  0.23,  0.30,  0.75,  1.50,  2.25,  3.01,  7.52, 15.03,  0.03,  0.08, 0.15,  0.23,  0.30,  0.75,  1.50,  2.25,  3.01,  7.52, 15.03,  0.03,  0.08,  0.15,  0.23,0.30,  0.75,  1.50,  2.25,  3.01,  7.52, 15.03)  
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y)) 
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = log10(y) ~ c1*log10(x)+c2,
              method.args=list(start=list(c1=-0.2,c2=-0.4)),
              aes(y = stage(y, after_stat = 10^y)),
              se=FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! Back-transforming the y variable via stage has perfectly solved my problem!